# how to add multiple data in qrcode using java

Tags: java, netbeans, qr-code

I hav written a simple code to generate qrcode.

```
public class GenQR {

    GenQR()
    {
        String name= "Syeda Tabassum";
        String occu="Student";
        String dob="20-may-1997";
       // String email="tabasum@gmail.com";
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) 
    {
        GenQR obj=new GenQR();

        try{

            String filedata="hello people";
            String filepath="H:\\QRdata\\data.jpg";
            String charset="UTF-8";
            Map <EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintmap=new HashMap <EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
            hintmap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
            MultiFormatWriter mfw=new MultiFormatWriter();
            BitMatrix bm= mfw.encode(new String(filedata.getBytes(charset),charset),BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200,hintmap);     
            MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(bm, filepath.substring(filepath
            .lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(filepath));
            System.out.println("QR Code image created successfully!");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am aiming to make a simple desktop application where user could generate his qrcode , so that upon scanning the QR code it would should details like: Name, age, gender, email-id, contactno. and any other relevant data to create an ID.

Can anybody help me out ,how to do that?

Comment: what part specifically ?

Comment: You can use zxing library for QR code creation, and iText for showing it on PDF, if iText5 not completely opensource though, you should read about that too.